# after saving Lead record it should take to Opportunity Creation

Tags: apex, trigger

if Lead status = closed and reason = "somthing". after saving the record it should take me to create a new opportunity.

Is it possible with trigger or process builder ?

Comment: Like a lead convert?

Comment: asd EricSSH says - standard and intended SFDC behavior is for the user to click Convert Lead that in turn creates (attaches to) Account, Contact, and Opportunity with Lead fields mapped to fields on Account-Contact-Opportunity. No need to reinvent the wheel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. Here is the code :

trigger toOppo on Lead (after update) {

```
list<lead> l = trigger.new;

for(lead l1:l){

    if((l1.status=='Closed - Converted') && (l1.reason!=' ')){

    opportunity o = new opportunity();
    o.Name=l1.Name;
    o.closeDate=date.today();
    o.StageName='Prospecting';
insert o;

    }

}
```

}